# JS: Item List - copy value content to clipboard

Tags: javascript, copy, listviewitem

I have a item list (listview), something like this:

```
<option value="String I want to get copied" title="String I want to get copied">Item1</option>
<option value="String I want to get copied-1" title="String I want to get copied-1">Item2</option>
```

I need to get copied to clipboard the content of (Please, attention!) Title or Value, but **NOT** "Item1" or "Item2".

Select an item- Right click-Copy the value or title field to clipboard...

It would be great if it possible to do it via menu right mouse click (I'm making a chrome extension). But any idea where to dig will be much appreciated!

Comment: So what did you try to do?

Comment: I need to select the item in the listview, then click the button and the "String I want to get copied" -voila, in my clipboard!

Answer (score 0):

Did you Try using clipboard js - https://clipboardjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Basically with JavaScript, you can't copy not printed text.
You can request special permission to do it but is not compatible with all web browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard

For that you need to use a flash plugin.

Comment: I can parse the page, isn't it?

Comment: Yes if your text is visible on the web page, there is technically no problems

Answer (score 0):

Generally access to clipboard is restricted in JavaScript for security reasons. (esp for browser plugins). So you will have to use third party solutions (like flash) There are some APIs available like exeCommand to hack around it: [execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)